# A proper way to save accented letters or special characters and sanitize them

Tags: php, sanitization

So I want to save some special characters in the DB, such as: á, é, í, ó, ú, ñ, Ñ... so, if I use:

```
$title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

as far I understand it will trip all tags and leave only the string letters and numbers also the special chars... So if my title is "Algúnos árboles"(few trees) it will store as is, if I use:

```
$title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, '$title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$title = $con->real_escape_string($title);
```

it still saving the data as is ú as ú and á as á, I have no problem with that, my table collation is utf8_general_ci, anyway, the problem here is when I display the information:

```
<?php
 // query to get the informacion
 echo $t['title'];
?>
```

It will display a � < ? > instead of the actual character even tho the html is set to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

so that is a problem... now if I don't use:

```
$title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
// instead I use
$title = htmlentities($_POST['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
$title = $con->real_escape_string($title);
```

The "accented" letters get saved as `&aacute;` for á... if I echo it it will show the actual character.

I have seen a few DB's where the character are stored as is(á, é, í...), and that is a problem to display it... So.

What is the best way to sanitize the strings then escape_string and then save it? then you can just retrieve it without thinking that you might get some estrange symbol...

I'm trying to use as minimum code as possible

Comment: did you send that header (top of the page) ? `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: yes, right after the `<head>` in the HTML, I also was did a raw echo in php before the HTML, in the PHP I set it as `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and I had the same result... so I have not idea why that is happening...

Comment: In UTF-8, those characters are represented using multiple bytes. Since filter_input isn't documented to handle UTF-8, I guess that it simply doesn't. Another question is the encoding of the DB. When set to UTF-8, there shouldn't be a technical need to discriminate different scripts. Try `mb_check_encoding()` to determine whether you have UTF-8, btw.